# Authenticate A User Instance not working Laravel 5.0

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I try to authenticate user but nothing happens 
in controller

I do the next

```
$authUser = User::where('password', md5($user->salt . $request->get('password')))
                  ->where('email', $request->get('email'))
                  ->first(['login', 'email', 'firstname', 'lastname', 'zip_code','phone']);
if ($authUser) {
   Auth::login($authUser);
   return response()->json(['user' => $authUser]);
}
```

response returns me user but for next request I get error that user not authenticated. Any idea?

Comment: Please post more detailed questions

Comment: But why you are not directly using auth::attempt ?

Comment: Because in  auth::attempt If the user is found, the hashed password stored in the database will be compared with the hashed password value passed to the method via the array. In database used md5 hashing with custom random generation salt and Laravel used another function for hashing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hello it's happens because you forgot to add id field to array of returned fields, so try add it like

```
$authUser = User::where('password', md5($user->salt . $request->get('password')))
                  ->where('email', $request->get('email'))
                  ->first(['id', 'login', 'email', 'firstname', 'lastname', 'zip_code','phone']);
if ($authUser) {
   Auth::login($authUser);
   return response()->json(['user' => $authUser]);
}
```